# deploy two project on the same container in CircleCi

Tags: containers, circleci

I have two separate projects(as two different repositories on GitHub) as client and server and they are communicating via WebSocket.
the Server is configured on CircleCi with the following docker entries:
installing "server".

```
docker:
          - image: cimg/base:stable
            auth:
                username: mydockerhub-user
                password: $DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD
            environment:
                CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE: Release
                INSTALL: ~/server-install
```

how can I use the already established Server docker image for my client,
deploying my client and server to the same container?